# Calculating sub-total in each group

Tags: sql-server, grouping, subtotal

I need report from multi table I use this query (SQL Server)

```
Select  CASE When ([bills].[BT] ='0' and [bills].[T] = 1 )Then 'Purchas1'
When([bills].[BT] ='0' and [bills].[T] = 3 ) Then 'Output'
When([bills].[BT] ='0' and [bills].[T] = 4 ) Then 'Input' 
When [bills].[BT] ='1'  Then  'ٍSales'
When [bills].[BT] = '2' Then  'Prch2'
When [bills].[BT] = '3' Then  'ٍSales2'
When [bills].[BT] = '4'  Then 'SInput' 
END AS BillType,
[mat].[Name] as Product,
[mat].[Code], [store].[Name], 
SUM( [billInfo].[qty]) as Qtys 
from [mat],[billInfo000],[store],[bu],[bills] 
Where [bu].[TG] =[bills].[g]
and [billInfo].[ParentGUID] =[bu].[g] 
and [billInfo].[StoreGUID] =[store].[g] 
and [billInfo].[MatGUID] = [mat].[g] 
Group by [bills].[BT],[bills].[T],[mat].[Name], 
[mat].[Code],[store].[Name] ,[mat].[qty]
```

what i want is adding one row after each group with Calculating
If it's same Product and same code and store i need
collect purchase1+Input+Prch2+SInput minus Sales, Output, Sales2
Like This:

```
BillType | Product | Code | Name | Qtys 
--------   -------   ----   ----   ---- 
Purchas1   Pro1      001    Main    150
Output     Pro1      001    Main    10
Sales      Pro1      001    Main    30
Purch2     Pro1      001    Main    50
Balance    Pro1      001    Main    160
Output     Pro1      001    Branch  10
Sales      Pro1      001    Branch  10
Balance    Pro1      001    Brabch  -20
```

Thanks

Comment: What implementation of SQL?  SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL? PostgreSQL?

Comment: Do you require this to be done in a single SQL Statement? I don't think it's possible but if it is, I'm interested in seeing that wonderful sql statement. Doing it in a stored proc should be easy, though.

Comment: @Icarus - I think it may be possible with a `ROLLUP` but I haven't played with them much

Comment: @JNK thanks for the hint. I'll look it up. Didn't know about it. :)

Comment: @Icarus it won't work for this exact scenario since he has some custom logic, but `ROLLUP` will total a `GROUP BY` for all groups basically

Comment: @Mohammed you should fix the tags then!

Comment: It appears that if this is a SQL Server query, all @Mohammed needs to do is add a WITH ROLLUP clause after the Group BY. See this example: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/24/sql-server-introduction-to-rollup-clause/

Comment: @lcarus I'm beginner user, How to do this in a stored proc?

Comment: @lcarus Thanks, but I can't use minus in that example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a `ROLLUP` but using a `WITH` statement and a `UNION` could do the trick just as wel.

The gist of it is to

- Store your original query in `q` using the `WITH` statement
- `SELECT` all from `q`
- Further refine the `GROUP BY` again from `q`to calculate the balances
- `UNION` the results together

#### SQL Server 2000

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
          SELECT  CASE  WHEN ([bills].[BT] ='0' and [bills].[T] = 1 ) THEN 'Purchas1'
                        WHEN ([bills].[BT] ='0' and [bills].[T] = 3 ) THEN 'Output'
                        WHEN ([bills].[BT] ='0' and [bills].[T] = 4 ) THEN 'Input' 
                        WHEN [bills].[BT] = '1' THEN 'Sales'
                        WHEN [bills].[BT] = '2' THEN 'Prch2'
                        WHEN [bills].[BT] = '3' THEN 'Sales2'
                        WHEN [bills].[BT] = '4' THEN 'SInput' 
                  END AS BillType
                  , [mat].[Name] AS Product
                  , [mat].[Code]
                  , [store].[Name]
                  , SUM([billInfo].[qty]) AS Qtys 
          FROM    [mat]
                  INNER JOIN [billInfo000] ON [billInfo000].[MatGUID] = [mat].[g]
                  INNER JOIN [store] ON [store].[g] = [billInfo0001].[StoreGUID]
                  INNER JOIN [bu] ON [bu].[g] = [billInfo000].[ParentGUID]
                  INNER JOIN [bills] ON [bills].[g] = [bu].[TG]
          GROUP BY
                [bills].[BT]
                , [bills].[T]
                , [mat].[Name]
                , [mat].[Code]
                , [store].[Name]
                , [mat].[qty]
        ) bt
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Balance'
        , Product
        , Code
        , Name
        , SUM(
            CASE  WHEN BillType = 'Purchas1' THEN Qtys
                  WHEN BillType = 'Output' THEN Qtys * -1
                  WHEN BillType = 'Sales' THEN Qtys * -1
                  WHEN BillType = 'Purch2' THEN Qtys
            END)
FROM    (
          SELECT  CASE  WHEN ([bills].[BT] ='0' and [bills].[T] = 1 ) THEN 'Purchas1'
                        WHEN ([bills].[BT] ='0' and [bills].[T] = 3 ) THEN 'Output'
                        WHEN ([bills].[BT] ='0' and [bills].[T] = 4 ) THEN 'Input' 
                        WHEN [bills].[BT] = '1' THEN 'Sales'
                        WHEN [bills].[BT] = '2' THEN 'Prch2'
                        WHEN [bills].[BT] = '3' THEN 'Sales2'
                        WHEN [bills].[BT] = '4' THEN 'SInput' 
                  END AS BillType
                  , [mat].[Name] AS Product
                  , [mat].[Code]
                  , [store].[Name]
                  , SUM([billInfo].[qty]) AS Qtys 
          FROM    [mat]
                  INNER JOIN [billInfo000] ON [billInfo000].[MatGUID] = [mat].[g]
                  INNER JOIN [store] ON [store].[g] = [billInfo0001].[StoreGUID]
                  INNER JOIN [bu] ON [bu].[g] = [billInfo000].[ParentGUID]
                  INNER JOIN [bills] ON [bills].[g] = [bu].[TG]
          GROUP BY
                [bills].[BT]
                , [bills].[T]
                , [mat].[Name]
                , [mat].[Code]
                , [store].[Name]
                , [mat].[qty]
        ) balance
GROUP BY
        Product
        , Code
        , Name
```

#### SQL Server 2005+

```
;WITH q AS (
  SELECT  CASE  WHEN ([bills].[BT] ='0' and [bills].[T] = 1 ) THEN 'Purchas1'
                WHEN ([bills].[BT] ='0' and [bills].[T] = 3 ) THEN 'Output'
                WHEN ([bills].[BT] ='0' and [bills].[T] = 4 ) THEN 'Input' 
                WHEN [bills].[BT] = '1' THEN 'Sales'
                WHEN [bills].[BT] = '2' THEN 'Prch2'
                WHEN [bills].[BT] = '3' THEN 'Sales2'
                WHEN [bills].[BT] = '4' THEN 'SInput' 
          END AS BillType
          , [mat].[Name] AS Product
          , [mat].[Code]
          , [store].[Name]
          , SUM([billInfo].[qty]) AS Qtys 
  FROM    [mat]
          INNER JOIN [billInfo000] ON [billInfo000].[MatGUID] = [mat].[g]
          INNER JOIN [store] ON [store].[g] = [billInfo0001].[StoreGUID]
          INNER JOIN [bu] ON [bu].[g] = [billInfo000].[ParentGUID]
          INNER JOIN [bills] ON [bills].[g] = [bu].[TG]
  GROUP BY
        [bills].[BT]
        , [bills].[T]
        , [mat].[Name]
        , [mat].[Code]
        , [store].[Name]
        , [mat].[qty]
)
SELECT  *
FROM    q
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Balance'
        , Product
        , Code
        , Name
        , SUM(
            CASE  WHEN BillType = 'Purchas1' THEN Qtys
                  WHEN BillType = 'Output' THEN Qtys * -1
                  WHEN BillType = 'Sales' THEN Qtys * -1
                  WHEN BillType = 'Purch2' THEN Qtys
            END)
FROM    q
GROUP BY
        Product
        , Code
        , Name
```

Comment: Thanks @Lieven,
It's seems work well in my PC
But when I tried to Test it on the client Server, which works on SQL-Server 2000 :(
I face problem With "With"
What should I do to make it work in both SQL-Server 2000 and 2008 ?

Comment: @Mohammed Rabee - WITH is SQL Server 2005 +. To have it work for SQL Server 2000, all you need to do is replace every instance of `q`(two of them) with the `SELECT` statement inside `WITH` (and drop `WITH`offcourse)

Comment: I don't know where I made ​​a mistake
But it's not working :(

Comment: @Mohammed Rabee - I have added the query for SQL Server 2000.